# How to pass an environment variable containing a string and quotation marks through the preprocessor in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor

The whole story first:

I'm refactoring some legacy code that contains a number of the following lines:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "D:\\Some\\absolute\\path\\to\\some\\library.lib")
```

For reasons I can not explain here, I need to have relative paths here. It would have been nice, if something like this

```
#pragma comment(lib, "to\\some\\library.lib")
```

and putting "D:\Some\absolute\path\" in the library dirs properties would've worked, but it doesn't and I do understand why.

My current approach is to (i) define D:\Some\absolute\path as a user macro SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH, then (ii) add SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH#$(SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH) to the preprocessor definitions which results in a compiler call

```
cl ... /D "SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH#D:\Some\absolute\path\"
```

I then use this definition in the code like this

```
#pragma comment(lib, SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH ## "to\\some\\library.lib")
```

which doesn't work. Looking at the preprocessor output this is expanded to this

```
#pragma comment(lib, D:\Some\absolute\path\ ## "to\\some\\library.lib")
```

which is certainly due to me not passing the quotation marks right in some place. Adding  quotation marks to the user macro (i) doesn't help because this results in

```
cl ... /D "SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH#"D:\Some\absolute\path\""
```

which the command line interpreter cannot correctly parse.

How do you do this right? I'm also open for any other solution fulfilling the constraint, that I can have some relative path in the pragma directive.

Comment: Did you try `".\to\\some\\library.lib"`?

Comment: The path is not actually relative to the source file. I just need a way to make the root of the path variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define STRINGISE2(X) #X
#define STRINGISE(X) STRINGISE2(X)

#pragma comment(lib, STRINGISE(SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH) "to\\some\\library.lib")
```

Comment: That took me a huge step closer to the goal, thanks. However, I still have some problems with escape characters etc. But I guess that only needs some more fiddling out.